# VS2010 ASP.NET web app solution unavailable issue

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an ASP.NET project managed in the VS 2010 IDE. I constantly copy it from one development machine to another. By its nature this ASP.NET project must run on an actual IIS. One development machine has a local IIS configured but I couldn't set it up on a second machine. The project is set up to `Use local IIS` in its properties. The issue happens when I try to copy this project from a machine with the local IIS to the one that does not have it. When I load it up in VS 2010 the only thing I get in the "Solution Explorer" is `<SolutionName> (Unavailable)` and I can't do anything, even open up its properties. The only way to fix this is to go back to the first machine and set up this project to `Use Visual Studio Development Server` and then copy it.

Is there any way to do this on the destination machine without this route of going back to the first computer?

Comment: it's in one of the visual studio files, the setting on which server setup to use, just don't copy that file to your other machine.

Comment: @ChrisBain: Can you be more specific?

Comment: as soon as I'm on my workstation tomorrow, I'll find exactly which file. sorry for the delay!